# grub Refresh or Resolution Too High. How can I adjust it?

Tags: 12.04, grub2, resolution, bootloader

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 using the Windows installer while in Windows XP. When I reboot and select Ubuntu as my boot option my monitor tells me "Out of range"

I believe at this point I would be looking at the grub bootloader and could choose regular or safe boot for linux and the default option is likely selecting after several seconds. After waiting several minutes (when ubuntu would be fully loaded) the resolution or refresh rate are still too high or low for me to do or see anything.

My monitor tells me the W refresh is 40hz (too low) and H is 80hz (too high.) I would like to adjust the resolution for grub and ubuntu to resolution to 1024*768 and refresh rate to 60hz, I believe then I will be able to see things after choosing Ubuntu from the windows bootloader.

How can I go about adjusting this, considering I am unable to see anything in the bootloader or ubuntu OS? I am able to work with Windows XP still if that opens up any options.

Answer (score 0):

There are already many questions and answers like this.

In short:

1. Boot in recovery mode  - instruction here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode You will be able to adjust all settings (text mode only).
2. Follow directions in this post - [Screen Resolution "Out of Range"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185502/screen-resolution-out-of-range)
3. For more information use Google search. Keywords - "ubuntu out of range 2013 OR 2014"
4. If you are absolutely out of luck - post more information, at least video card name and version. I think you should change X11 settings too.